# Does a Strix drinking the breath of a victim exsanguinate the victim?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

The Strix can gain "Vitae" by stealing breath. This reminds me a bit of the Succubi Chi stealing in "Lost Girl", at least in its general description. I'm left wondering though, when a Strix isn't riding a vampire, and is instead stealing breath, is a drained body lacking blood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stealing breath is described as being instead of drinking blood, and is impossible to do with a soulless victim (B&S201). Additionally, it does not work on revenants and vampires.

It's pretty clear to me that there is no physical removal of blood. The body would not be drained; I'd portray it as some sort of traumatic suffocation (given that it does lethal damage).

Comment: Autopsy: victim's lungs completely imploded.